# unable to retrieve all data from httpResponse

Tags: java, android, http, httpwebresponse

After I try different way, i cannot able to retrieve all data from `HttpResponse`.

Here is my code :

```
private static final DefaultHttpClient httpClient =
    new DefaultHttpClient();

public void get() throws Exception {
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://dt.abc.net/abc.exe");

    httpPost.addHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/xml;charset=UTF-8")

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("XML", 
            getRequestTypeStringBuilder()));

    // In here "XML" is parameter value that is required send to the server 
    // before request data from server.

    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setStaleCheckingEnabled(params, false);
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 5000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 5000);
    httpClient.setParams(params);
    httpClient.getParams().setParameter(
            ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.RFC_2109);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

    InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();

    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf;
    int ByteRead;
    buf = new byte[1024];

    String xmldata = null;
    while ((ByteRead = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1) {
        os.write(buf, 0, ByteRead);
        totalSize += ByteRead;                      
    }

    xmldata =  os.toString().replaceAll(" ", "");
    os.close();
    is.close();
}
```

A problem is, if i set content-type = "application/xml" and try to retrieve data  from remote server, which is in large amount, it could not retrieve all data. However, if data is reletively small, then it works perfect.

All return data are in XML format

Another problem if i change content-type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded", it throws and exception :

```
01-05 18:59:53.165: WARN/System.err(372): javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Read error: ssl=0x2f9698: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
01-05 18:59:53.195: WARN/System.err(372):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
01-05 18:59:53.208: WARN/System.err(372):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:786)
01-05 18:59:53.215: WARN/System.err(372):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
01-05 18:59:53.236: WARN/System.err(372):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:134)
01-05 18:59:53.236: WARN/System.err(372):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.IdentityInputStream.read(IdentityInputStream.java:86)
01-05 18:59:53.246: WARN/System.err(372):     at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:159)
01-05 18:59:53.286: WARN/System.err(372):     at com.epsilon.android.dreammailandroid.remoteserver.AsyncDownloadDataInsert.doInBackground(AsyncDownloadDataInsert.java:111)
01-05 18:59:53.295: WARN/System.err(372):     at com.epsilon.android.dreammailandroid.remoteserver.AsyncDownloadDataInsert.doInBackground(AsyncDownloadDataInsert.java:1)
01-05 18:59:53.316: WARN/System.err(372):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
01-05 18:59:53.316: WARN/System.err(372):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
01-05 18:59:53.335: WARN/System.err(372):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
01-05 18:59:53.335: WARN/System.err(372):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
01-05 18:59:53.346: WARN/System.err(372):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
01-05 18:59:53.396: WARN/System.err(372):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
01-05 18:59:55.764: WARN/InputManagerService(61): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4065a640
```

I couldn't understand why i couldn't get all data in response.

Could you help me, figure out what is problem in my code.

Note: I retrieve data from android application.

Thank you,

"May all being be happy"

Regards and Metta,
Ichirohang Limbu

Comment: Are you calling this function from some UI event handler?

Comment: Yeah right, I use android AsyncTask. Does it make different?

Comment: does anyone noticed there is a syntax error at the 8th line from top of the code? `httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/xml;charset=UTF-8")`

Comment: just an observation.but why are you not trying to check the HTTP status code befoer you retrieve?

Answer (score 0):

If the returned data is text/xml, you could try:

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
String content = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Comment: Hi Dave, I try that way also, but couldn't work. I check it only retrievs around 332 kilobytes of data. Any suggestion

Comment: Have you tried using: `HttpPost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` and also `httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,HTTP.UTF_8));`

Comment: Hi Dave, Thank you for your quick respond. well, I try httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodeFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));  However, in HttpPost.setHeader is set ("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"), It still does not return all data. I have also another parameter in  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LoginId", "abc")); and  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", "123")); does it effect in reponse data? Do i need to set content-length in header? Any suggestion

Comment: Does it always return exactly the same 332k of data every time you run it?  Or is the exact amount of returned data different each time?

Comment: Yeah, every time it return 332k if data are larger, and exit from the loop. Is it cause by android emulator memory?

Comment: You can test that by running your code in a pure Java project and executing it from a `main` method from the command line or IDE.

Comment: Hi Dave, Thank you. I check with other IPhone application, that also return 332K total data. It means response return all the data. However, when ByteArrayOutputStream().toString() it does not push out all data. I use another method HttpUrlConnection. However, HttpUrlConnection through an exception Socket is closed after it retrieve around 315K data. Sure, I will try from pure Java Project.

Comment: i have the same problem .did u find any solutuin,

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates an SSL level or a network issue. Either of these issues occur in a layer below Http protocol error and I suspect connect type advice above may not be germane.

javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Read error: ssl=0x2f9698: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
01-05 18:59:53.195: WARN/System.err(372):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
01-05 18:59:53.208: WARN/System.err(372):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:786)

Answer (score 0):

Trying checking if it's not timing out